# Java String Internationalization Supporting RTL with Parameters

Tags: string, templates, java-8, locale

I need to display an error message in my program, using parameters (or templates if you prefer) such as:

`Connection to {0} failed with {1} status`

The string is already compiled (translated) for the locale, but **I'm wondering if I need to write a function to fill the template, or if there is already one available within standard Java 8**.

I tried the `{N}` (parameter keys) in my translator, and luckily the languages i am targeting won't translate the parameter keys, but they will "mangle" standard java/C-style things like `%s`, so a `String.format()` call won't work without some custom overhead.

I've been working through the problem up to this point, and as far as I know this is the best way to support RTL and LTR internationalization for error messages.

If you know of a better method (that doesn't involve libraries) i am all for hearing your answer and/or comments.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [one of the oldest Java text processing features](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/text/MessageFormat.html) and existed long before the support for C-style format strings had been added to Java:

```
String param1 = "google.com", param2 = "ACCESS DENIED";

String formatted = MessageFormat.format(
    "Connection to {0} failed with {1} status", param1, param2);

System.out.println(formatted);
```

The method used above is already a convenience method for

```
String param1 = "google.com", param2 = "ACCESS DENIED";
String f = "Connection to {0} failed with {1} status";

MessageFormat format = new MessageFormat(f);
String formatted = format.format(new Object[] {param1, param2});

System.out.println(formatted);
```

which eliminates the need to declare another `static` helper method on your own.

When the C-style formatting feature was added in Java 5, it got prominently placed convenience methods in the `String` class, however, I would be reluctant to call the C-style format the “standard java/C-style”. When you look at the `java.text` API with the date, number, choice, and message formatter and how you can embed the former into the latter, you’ll notice how it is more powerful than Java 5’s new `java.util.Formatter` feature whereas there’s unfortunately no interaction between these features.

The even newer `java.time` API has formatters/parser on its own, but provides a bridge to the `java.text` API, though you can’t embed them into a `MessageFormat` the same way. And it doesn’t provide any interaction with the `java.util.Formatter` API.

So the Java formatting API is a patchwork of insulated features. But note that when you are about to use these messages with a logging API, chances are high, that it does already use the `MessageFormat` when you log with parameters, like `logger.log(Level.ERROR, "Connection to {0} failed with {1} status", param1, param2);` You should check the logging API’s documentation in that regard.

Comment: I am accepting your answer as the preferred solution, but other comers, who are interested should note, that there is no guarantee that the `{N}` parameters won't be mangled by a language translator, which would break this functionality as a viable option, and would require a custom static method to inflate the template using a specific parameter key embedding scheme. [thanks for the high-quality-answer, your work is much appreciated.]

Comment: "standard java/C-style" is quite reflective of the fact that the `%s` usage is a shared format-style across language boundaries, though there are notable differences in implementation with numbers, my specific usage is in regard to strings, not numbers (which use slightly different format signifiers). The forward solidus (`/`), for all intents and purposes means `OR`. So, whether we use Java or C, `%` based-format-specifiers are not a viable option. [note]

Comment: Yes, translators have to be aware of the non-translatable placeholders. But, as said, the `{n}` format is Java's oldest, existing since 1993 and supported by most supporting tools.

Answer (score 0):

So, while waiting, i came up with this as a base function, which can be called directly, or by a specific case handler:

```java
public static String compileLocaleTemplate(String template, String... parameters){
    for (int i=0; i < parameters.length; i++){
        String tag = "{"+i+"}";
        template = template.replace(tag, parameters[i]);
    }
    return template;
}
```

Its quick and dirty, as it doesn't do any error checking, but it should work (in theory).